# How can I use an external hard drive as an internal one virtually?

Tags: windows

You might be thinking that I want to connect my external hard drive using SATA cables as an internal one....But no, that's what I don't want to do. Is there any way that I can connect an external hard drive using an USB connection and configure it using some software perhaps, which will enable me to use it as an internal one, so that I can move my operating system (Windows 10) and Applications to my external hard drive and use the internal one for files such as documents- storage? Any idea how to do that!?

Comment: The solution to this is probably entirely a software matter, with no special hardware involved.

Comment: Even if you do find the software to do this, I would highly recommend against doing this. The safeguards exist in the first place for a reason. It would suck if your entire operating system got corrupted because a usb hard drive got kicked loose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the same thing on Linux, but it should not matter. I just install whole system on USB flash and setup in BIOS to boot from USB  first.

Now it finds the USB on start, boots from it, sets the whole system, connects to net and does the usuall daily tasks. I can connect remotly, setup encription and connect internal hard drives encrypted, if I need so.

Those internal HDDs contains just5 encrypted data, nothing else, the USB flash contains the full system and can be used to rescue any USB bootable computer (nearly any nowadays).

As flash is not good for too many writes, I load as much as possible of the system to memory at start and I set the logs to RAM disc entirly, so th USB can be read-only. Takes more time to boot (USB is always slower than native connection), but I do not care. I can get the system anywhere else leave the computer with encrypted data discs only, not being able to boot. I can use the flash on any other computer to get my system working.

In Windows case it would mean to install the windows on the USB only (or start with some rescue flash and expand its content, then maybe copy it to USB disc. The disc probably needs to be market "bootable" and you need to set the computer BIOS to boot first from remote media - either as default option, or as backup option and do not make internal disc bootable, or just press propper key on boot to select boot media from list of aviable devices.

As I do not use Windows for many years (from when XP was hot new), I cannot provide step to step instruction, but maybe Windows are not so bad, that they would not enable "rescue system" to lay on USB media and to be customized ...

Comment: Yep. I got it pretty much. I'm using WinToUSB for this. I configured UEFI in BIOS and formatted by exHDD using MBR. Works great